# MMD tables to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with `MathPix` to transform pdf to tables. At the end I need to save the text formatting. The issue here are the tables, as in mmd output of `mathpix` is hard to transform to dataframe. Below is the example of some tables:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline & & & VALUE & UNIT \\
\hline \multirow[b]{2}{*}{\(\mathrm{V}_{(\mathrm{ESD})}\)} & \multirow[b]{2}{*}{ Electrostatic discharge } & Human-body model (HBM), per ANSI/ESDA/JEDEC JS-001(1) & \pm 2000 & \multirow[b]{2}{*}{\(\mathrm{V}\)} \\
\hline & & \(\begin{array}{l}\text { Charged-device model (CDM), per JEDEC specification JESD22- } \\
\text { C101(2) }\end{array}\) & \pm 750 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{ STATUS } & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ AVDD } \\
\cline { 2 - 5 } & \(\mathbf{5} \mathbf{V}\) & \(\mathbf{3 . 3} \mathbf{V}\) & \(\mathbf{2 . 7} \mathbf{~ V}\) & \(\mathbf{2 . 2} \mathbf{~ V}\) \\
\hline Idle & \(1 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(1 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(20 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(15 \mu \mathrm{A}\) \\
\hline Awake & \(45 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(25 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(275 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(270 \mu \mathrm{A}\) \\
\hline Acquiring & \(315 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(285 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(450 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(400 \mu \mathrm{A}\) \\
\hline Converting & \(730 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(520 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(2 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(1.25 \mu \mathrm{A}\) \\
\hline Sleeping & \(3 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(2 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \(1.5 \mu \mathrm{A}\) & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline MODE & \\
\hline Idle & All circuits shutdown; lowest power setting \\
\hline Awake & All circuits awake and ready to convert \\
\hline Manual-Single & Select input channel is converted once \\
\hline Manual-Scan & All input channels are converted once \\
\hline Auto-Single & One input channel is continuously converted \\
\hline Auto-Scan & All input channels are continuously converted \\
\hline Auto-Single with Sleep & One input channel is continuously converted with programmable sleep time between conversions \\
\hline Auto-Scan with Sleep & All input channels are continuously converted with programmable sleep time between conversions \\
\hline \(\begin{array}{c}\text { Auto-Burst Scan with } \\
\text { Sleep }\end{array}\) & All input channels are converted with minimal delay followed by a programmable sleep time \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

3rd table is pretty easy to conver to dataframe, but first 2 has the trick names multicolumn and multirow. Is there pre-written library to transform such kind of mmd tables to any dataframes or related forms? I tried to apply some algorithms but it failed miserably.

Comment: It is not easy to convert `LaTeX` tabular environments to `Pandas DataFrame` when there are complex formatting directives such as `multirow`, `multicolumn`, etc. As far as I know, there is no specific library that supports this transformation directly.

Comment: You could also try to convert to pdf, then to dataframe with an existing library like [tabula](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Or maybe through HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment to the question I think this has to be done "manually"

First, you need to parse the LaTeX structure using a LaTeX Parser. Then, you need to create custom logic to merge cells based on the `Multirow` and `Multicolumn` directives, and finally, you need to convert the structured LaTeX structure into a `DataFrame`. For `Multirow`, you need to merge multiple cells in the row into one, and for `Multicolumn`, you need to divide the table into multiple rows. Finally, you need to track the cells that are being "span" by a `Multirow` from a Previous Line as each new line is processed. The first step is to parse LaTeX. This can be done by using the `pylatxenc` library, which can be used to copy code and install it to LaTeX sources. Once the LaTeX structure is processed, the next step is to build a `DataFrame`.

This approach is highly abstracted and would take a lot of time and effort to implement. Edge cases would also need to be handled. A second approach is to pre-process LaTeX tables into a simple form and write a simple converter for that form. If LaTeX tables aren’t very diverse, then you can use this approach. If you can change the way you’re extracting the data from `MathPix`, you might want to consider exporting to a format that’s easier to work with, if that’s possible.